# How to convert selected Spinner item to String

Tags: java, android, string, android-spinner

I was playing around with Spinners in Android, and after some playing I had a problem with  getting the selected spinner item and convert it to a String.

Can someone explain to me how to do this properly?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post your code pls.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Great question! And I hope you haven't lost your drive for Android development.

What you are missing is an ItemListener. Below is an example of how to get the data from your spinner:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewbyId(R.id.<your id in your xml>)
```

Then create a listener to for that item:

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 String dataWanted = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); }

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {            
        }
    });
```